# ALT F -> Fill not working correctly?

Tags: edit-mode

Selection of vertices in the same plane does not fill correctly if I am to understand the `ALT F` function correctly. I would like the area marked in red to be filled.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

I removed duplicates prior to `ALT F`

[image]

Comment: wow but that's horrible topology. i wonder though what the best way is to fill it with a pretty quad topolgy. Is that even possible?